# code spontaneously executes at debug line without user input after a few seconds

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to debug a couple functions in shiny, so I put a `browser()` in and was stepping through the code. Unexpectedly, while I was not touching anything,  this warning appeared (repeated twice)

```
Warning in get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

the last command I entered was just `str()`ing a variable. I have no timing related execution rules in my code anywhere.

I can't even reproduce this even if I could include my whole program in this post, so a MRE is out of the question. Anyone have any deeper shiny knowledge about timed execution that would cause this to happen?

Comment: I have the same issue with basic R (no shiny app)